# Loop through all permutations 20 columns across 400 columns

Tags: excel, vba, data-science, permutation

I have a dataset of 400 columns and I would like to collect all permutations of 20 columns.

For example, the first run would return col [1, 2, 3 ... 18, 19, 20].

The next permutation would be columns [1, 2, 3 ... 18, 19, 21].

Until arg20 = 401 and arg 19 would be set to 20 and arg20 set to 21 [1, 2, 3 ... 18, 20, 21].

This would loop until all permutations have been achieved.

I've done this in 3 dimensions, but at 20 I'd like to ask the forum if there is an easier way than hard coding it...

My 'hardcoded' way would be something like an abacus:

```
For Arg1 = 1 To 398
   For Arg2 = 1 + Arg1 To 399
      For Arg3 = 1 + Arg2 To 400
          Capture what I want here
      Next Arg3
   Next Arg2
Next Arg1
```

But I'm not sure if I want 20, 10, 40 or 200 columns, so I'd like to not hard code it like this if possible. I'm also leery about the memory usage using this technique.

Anyone know a better way/method? It would save me some gray hair!

Comment: To calculate the number of selections of 20 items from 400  https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/combinations.php?n=400&r=20&action=solve The answer is 2788360983670896737872851072994080...  Are you sure you need to do this?

Comment: My bad, I am taking an average of values within these columns. The values within the columns would change with time. I'm just trying to write the method shell that tells which column to load the array at each step. I would add more code in the 'Capture what I want here' line nested in all the for loops.

Comment: What I'm getting at is do you know how long it would take to run that loop? Just a basic `For` loop from 1 to 1E9 takes just under 10secs in my VBE.  Your 20 from 400 is about 2.8E33 combinations (if I used the correct link above), so about 2.8e24 * 10sec, or roughly 9.5E17 years.

Comment: LOL well that would explain why excel stalled, left it on overnight and was still running in the morning. I'm only using 300 records per column but I think I will find a better strategy. Thank you for your insight!